# How to include Related Posts in WP RSS feed

Tags: posts, rss, feed

How to include Related Posts in WP RSS feed not use plugin?
I have search around on google and stackexchange but have no result about this.
Thanks all friends!

Comment: Do you mean how to compute related posts or how to place them in feed when they are already computed?

Comment: Yes! I want to place them in feed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `the_content` and `the_excerpt_rss` hooks. You can do this like this:

```
function rss_append_footer($content) {
    if(is_feed()) {
        $related_posts_html = ...  // I assume you already can compute it
        $content .= $related_posts_html;
    }
    return $content;
}

add_filter('the_content', 'rss_append_footer');
add_filter('the_excerpt_rss', 'rss_append_footer');
```